# Heading estimation for differential drive robot

Tags: slam, imu

My robot fried its BNO055 IMU, (which never gave the heading estimation improvement I sought), so I am investigating my options.  I noticed the ROS 2 iRobot Create uses wheel encoders, an optical flow sensor, and an IMU (I think) to produce its fused odometry.

I have seen reference to the effect that IMUs are not that great at yaw measurements, and also saw that optical flow sensors need an IMU to correct for roll and pitch.

Will fusing a new IMU, optical flow sensor, with my wheel encoder data likely stop SLAM from returning a slightly rotated heading after excursions around the room?